# Return next row in a dataframe R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
  kind  datetime 
  book   2016-04-23 04:23:00
  pen    2016-04-23 04:30:00
  toy    2016-04-23 06:45:00
```

I would like to return, for each row in my dataset, the datetime for the next row, so that my new dataframe will look like this:

```
  kind  datetime               next_time 
  book   2016-04-23 04:23:00   2016-04-23 04:30:00
  pen    2016-04-23 04:30:00   2016-04-23 06:45:00
  toy    2016-04-23 06:45:00
```

How can I do this in R? In SQL, I'd use the Lead function, but I'm not sure what to use in R!

Thanks!

Comment: In R you also use `lead` :). `df$next_time = dplyr::lead(df$datetime)`.

Comment: `df$next_time <- c(tail(df$datetime, -1), "")`

Comment: In `data.table` it's called `shift`, e.g. `df$next_time <- data.table::shift(df$datetime, 1, type = 'lead')`

Comment: `dfrm$nextime <- c(tail(dfrm$datetime,-1),NA)`